# Vue 3 equivalent of Vue.extend()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component

I'm trying to migrate to vue3 piece of next code from vue2:
Vue2 to vue3 **options** api
code in callback of other function that used in 3party pure js library

```
 const cls = Vue.extend(extendComponent);
 const instance = new cls({
      data: {
         obj: data,
         toolkit: toolkit,
         surface: surface,
         vertex: node
      },
      parent: parentComponent
                            
});
instance.$mount();

instance.$el._ref = instance;
return instance.$el;
```

Any thoughts? Thx a lot in advance!

I have tried to use createVNode and definedComponent but unsuccessful

Comment: Consider explaining your case in details, it depends on it. The equivalents are "extends" option for options api and composables for composition api

Answer (score 1):

Solution was:

```js
const el = document.createElement('div')
let vnode = createVNode({
        data: {
            obj: data,
            toolkit: toolkit,
            surface: surface,
            vertex: node
        },
        parent: toolkitComponent,
        extends: def.component })


const oel = render(vnode, el)


return vnode.el
```